# On mobile safari submit button doesn't work on first tap when keyboard is open

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, mobile-safari

I have a form with submit button. On Mobile safari ( iPhone) when the keyboard is open and you tap the submit button on form, it just closes the keyboard.
and then second tap submits the form.

The form is an AJAX form with remote=true

Comment: i've had the same problem. Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and in my case there was an other action what I made for `unfocus` for an input element, so first tap/click just was blocked by other action on which was on same time.